# Как реализовать считывания нажатия Checkbox

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть текстовый виджет и пару флажков.

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
var = IntVar()

def bar (event):
    if var==1:
        tex.insert(1.0,'1')    


fra=Frame(root)
fra.grid(row=0,columnspan=2)
tex=Text(fra,width=30)
tex.pack()


c1 = IntVar()
c2 = IntVar()
c3 = IntVar()
c4 = IntVar()
c5 = IntVar()
c6 = IntVar()
c7 = IntVar()
c8 = IntVar()
che1 = Checkbutton(root,text='1',
                   variable=var)
che1.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=10)
che2 = Checkbutton(root,text='2',
                   variable=c2,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
che2.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=50,pady=10)

che3 = Checkbutton(root,text='3',
                   variable=c3,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
che3.grid(row=3,column=0,pady=10)
che4 = Checkbutton(root,text='4',
                   variable=c4,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
che4.grid(row=4,column=0)

che5 = Checkbutton(root,text='5',
                   variable=c5,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
che5.grid(row=1,column=1)
che6 = Checkbutton(root,text='6',
                   variable=c6,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
che6.grid(row=2,column=1)

che7 = Checkbutton(root,text='7',
                   variable=c7,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
che7.grid(row=3,column=1)
che8 = Checkbutton(root,text='8',
                   variable=c8,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
che8.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=50,pady=10)

tex.bind('<Button-1>',bar)
root.mainloop()
```

Надо, чтобы по нажатию лкм на текстовое поле, отображалось количество включенных флажков. У меня не выходит передать состояние флажка функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `IntVar().get()` чтобы обработать значение `checkbox`   (не стал писать всю функцию я думаю вы дальше поняли как писать)

```
from tkinter import*


def bar(event):
    if var.get()==1:
        tex.insert(END, '1')
    if c1.get()==1:
        tex.insert(END, '2')


root=Tk()
var = IntVar()
fra=Frame(root)
fra.grid(row=0,columnspan=2)
tex=Text(fra,width=30)
tex.pack()


c1 = IntVar()

che1 = Checkbutton(root,text='1',
                   variable=var)
che1.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=10)
che2 = Checkbutton(root,text='2',
                   variable=c1,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
che2.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=50,pady=10)

tex.bind('<Button-1>',bar)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо=)))))))